# Eclipse editor hangs, how can I detect what's blocking it?

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-7

I have a rather large Eclipse 4.6.3 workspace with many Java EE 7 and E4 projects in it. Since some time (I think since I switched from Glassfish to JBoss/Wildfly) editing became quite a challenge. As soon as I type some background process is doing some work (CPU load between 10 and 25%) for and blocks the editing. After some seconds (sometimes even up to a minute) CPU load is back to zero.

How can I find out which background tasks are being executed? I have the progress window open but none are shown. Sometimes, I see that the editor tries to sync its views or that there's 'as you type JBT validation). I suspect, however, that these reported tasks, too, are slowed down by whatever is secretly industrious.

I have this issue on different machines, all of them fairly good ones. I have tried many things already such as closing a third of all projects, deactivating window syncing, starting eclipse with -clean or even -resetPersistedState, updating Eclipse components...

Thanks for any hints!
gufi

Comment: The editor itself may be using a 'reconciler' which runs in a background thread and can do a lot of work. I don't know of a way to see this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues (probably) found the source of the problem:

During editing any of the bean classes Eclipse synchronizes the deployment descriptor in the project explorer. As the project contains >100 beans this  takes some time and freezes my editing.

Resolution: In the project eplorer's view menu choose 'customize view', then on the content tab unselect the extensions that care about the deployment descriptor. These are the ones I chose:

- J2EE EJB Deployment Descriptors
- Java EE Navigator Content EJB
- J2EE Web Deployment Descriptors
- J2EE Application Deployment Descriptors

Kind regards
gufi